# Chevalley’s affineness criterion for perfectoid space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perfectoid-spaces

Chevalley’s affineness criterion says that if $f: X\to Y$ is surjective and finite, $Y$ is Noetherian and $X$ is affine then $Y$ is also affine. The usual proof uses Serre's criterion and Noetherian induction. I think Serre's criterion for affinoid perfectoids is open at present (it is false for general adic spaces. See problem 26 of Kedlaya's Scottish book). Is Chevalley’s affineness criterion true for perfectoid spaces?